# Can not import a zipped project to NetBeans

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans-7

When i tried to import a zipped project, it is not visible in Netbeans IDE, but added to the file location. How could i resolve this problem make my project available in Netbeans IDE.

Comment: unzip and then import the project.

Comment: is it valid netbeans project

Comment: The zipped project seems to be not a valid netbeans project! To have a valid neatbeans project,it should have architecture and directories similar to netbeans project! If it is simply a .java file or some Eclipse project,then it won't show under Netbeans window---Open project location. Please post the directories inside the project to get validated about netbeans project.

Comment: and if project is created in netbeans 8 you will not be able to open in 7

Comment: @FastSnail how did you solve it? I am in the same condition as you were.

Comment: @AryanG actually this question not asked by me.however this problem has happen to me sometimes.like kshitij kulshrestha said create new project and add all folders/files in to it from zip

Comment: @FastSnail It seemed to me that I was stuck with the version problem like you'd mentioned. But it turns out to be something else and I have solved it by now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new project in netbeans of the type you want,In the workspace folder will be created of the same name, you just extract all the files in that folder and then refresh in netbeans.

You are done :)

Answer (score 2):

To import a zipped file on net beans,ensure it is in ZIP format,not .RAR  or .RAR5 format.If your zipped folder is not visible when you want to import it,convert it to ZIP format using the following steps:

- Extract it into another folder
- Right click on the extracted folder then choose archive folder
- Then choose ZIP format and click okay

Answer (score 1):

Simple ways is to go to file menu then click on open project then go to the folder where your project files are present, You will see that your project is created just open it, so this should open your project without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is also because of the Netbeans plugin. Example, If you dont have "Java EE Base" Plugin installed, then you cant import java web projects into netbeans.